# WP Как отфильтровать посты сразу по двум рейтингам?

Tags: wordpress

[image: Фильтры]
Есть вот такие два фильтра. Первый забирает посты по массиву с их id второй по таксономии. Код выглядит так.

```
function all_reviews_filter_ajax()
{
    $arr_selected_supplements = $_POST['arr_selected_supplements'] ?? array();
    $arr_reviews_with_rating = $_POST['arr_reviews_with_rating'] ?? array();

    $posts_per_page = intval($_POST['posts_per_page']);
    $page = intval($_POST['page']);

    if (empty($arr_selected_supplements) && empty($arr_reviews_with_rating)) {
        $args = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'reviews',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'paged' => $page,
        );
    } else {
        $args = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'reviews',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
        if (is_array($arr_reviews_with_rating)) {
            global $r_5, $r_4, $r_3, $r_2;

            // Create a mapping array to associate values like "r_5" with the corresponding post IDs
            if (is_array($r_5) && is_array($r_4) && is_array($r_3) && is_array($r_2)) {
                $rating_mapping = array(
                    'r_5' => array_keys($r_5),
                    'r_4' => array_keys($r_4),
                    'r_3' => array_keys($r_3),
                    'r_2' => array_keys($r_2),
                );

                // Get post IDs based on selected values in $arr_reviews_with_rating
                $selected_ratings = array();
                foreach ($arr_reviews_with_rating as $value) {
                    if (isset($rating_mapping[$value])) {
                        $selected_ratings = array_merge($selected_ratings, $rating_mapping[$value]);
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($selected_ratings)) {
                    // This will filter posts that have matching ratings
                    $args['post__in'] = $selected_ratings;

                    error_log("Arr ids =" . print_r($selected_ratings, true));
                }
            } else {
                echo "not arrays";
            }
        }

        if (is_array($arr_selected_supplements)) {
            $arr_selected_supplements = array_map('intval', $arr_selected_supplements);
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'supplement_type',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $arr_selected_supplements,
                ),
            );
        }
    }


    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/review-item');
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results found.";
    }

    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_all_reviews_filter', 'all_reviews_filter_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_all_reviews_filter', 'all_reviews_filter_ajax');
```

По отдельности, они работают правильно. Но когда выбираються значения и с первого и с второго то посты не возвращаються. Мне необходимо, чтобы, если они соответствуют хотя бы одному из условий (или обоим) выводился список из ВСЕХ постов.(без повторов) В документации есть про параметр `'relation' => 'OR'` [для таксаномий](https://misha.agency/wordpress/wp_query.html)... но как быть в этом случаии. Подскажите, пожалуйста ?

Comment: Проблема не ясна, если честно. О каких условиях речь? Если два условия истинны, то Вам выведет посты с обозначенными ID и которые принадлежат выбранным термам обозначенной таксономии.

Comment: И я так думал, но если в массивах  $arr_selected_supplements и  $arr_reviews_with_rating одновременно имеются значения массивов, то почему-то отрабатывает вывод `echo "No results found.";`

Comment: Смотрите что в массивах, возможно там нет постов удовлетворяющих оба условия.